# Unable to locate element using XPath getting NoSuchElementException

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I am unable to click on logout link in my web page using XPath.

**XPath:** `html/body/div[1]/span/div[1]/a[1]`

I See my code in an attachment:

[image: my Code].

[image: HTML Script for "logout"]

Comment: //a[contains(text(),'[Logout]')] - This XPath will definitely works for you.

Comment: Try to wait for the webelement by using WebDriverWait class.

Answer (score 3):

Switch to the iframe first, for that try the below code.

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("iframe[src*=sfactory]")));
```

After that you can use the XPath or CSS selector to identify the locator.

css: `a[onclick*=exitAction]`

xpath: `//a[contains(@onclick, 'exitAction')]`

Answer (score 1):

Try with the below xpath.

```
//a[contains(text(),'Logout')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this below XPath.

```
//a[contains(text(),'[Logout]')]
```

Prefer Relative XPath rather than Absolute XPath.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code using LinkText locator for locating the logout button.

```
driver.findElementBy.linkText("[Logout]")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this below code.

```
//a[contains(.,'Logout')]
```

This should also work.